# d3 js - loading json

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Dynamically I need to pass the json data. I have AJAX success function

```
success: function (data) {

            //$("#showGraph").empty().append(data);
           // $("#showGraph").find(jsondata).append(data);
            $("#showGraph").find(jsondata).push(data) ;

            //console.log($("#showGraph").trigger('create').show());
        },
```

Here I am trying many ways to append the data dynamically. data contains the json.

```
// d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json", function(error, flare) {
    var jsondata;
     root = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

I am setting using a variable called jsondata. But I am not able to see the expected result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: have you event appended data to the jsondata variable ?